# Hibernate : Transaction commited but data not inserted to the Database

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I've got an unusual situation using Hibernate. I have a shopping cart in my web application. I used following methods to add or update cart.

`isItemExists(...)` - To check whether item already exists in the cart or not

`addItem()`         - Add item is item not exists or update existing item.

`incrementCartTotal(..)` -  To update cart total

**addItem(..)**

```
 public void addCartItem2(CartItems item, int qty) {
    Session ses = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tr = ses.beginTransaction();
    try {
        CartItems c1 = isItemExists(item.getModel(), item.getCart());

        if (c1 != null) {
            Double unitPrice = sModel.getStock(item.getModel()).getUnitPrice();

            Query q = ses.createQuery("UPDATE "
                    + " CartItems "
                    + " SET qty = qty + " + qty + " , sub_total = sub_total +" + qty * unitPrice
                    + " WHERE model_ID=" + c1.getModel().getId()
                    + "  AND cart_ID=" + c1.getCart().getId());
            q.executeUpdate();
        } else {
            ses.save(item);
        }

        tr.commit();

        incrementCartTotal(item.getCart(), NumberUtilities.parseDouble(item.getSubTotal()));

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.err(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (ses.isOpen()) {
            ses.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I can add or update cart items once. After I remove items from the cart I can't add or update items to the cart. But cart total is updating. Transaction commited but, data not inserted.

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Start by putting a break-point in your code at the point you call `ses.save` and see if that code is getting executed. That's the call that inserts your item, and I suspect it's not getting called.

Comment: SET qty = qty + " + qty , is the first 'qty' is variable or just a string?

Comment: @sForSujit : first qty is the database column name, Second one is a variable

Comment: Please post your isItemExists(...) method. I think the problem is there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
Do not use `addItem()` method to update and save.

- Use your `isItemExists()`  mthod to check whether item exists or not.
- If not create a method to save item
- If exists create another method to update existing item

**save()**

```
 public void save(CartItems item) {
    Session ses = factory.openSession();
    try {
        Transaction tr = ses.beginTransaction();
        ses.save(item);
        tr.commit();

        incrementCartTotal(item.getCart(), NumberUtilities.parseDouble(item.getSubTotal()));
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
       // handle exception
    } finally {
        // close session
    }
}
```

**update()**

```
 public void update(CartItems item,int qty, double price) {
    Session ses = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tr = ses.beginTransaction();
    try {
        Query q = ses.createQuery("UPDATE "
                + " CartItems "
                + " SET qty = qty + "+qty+" , sub_total = sub_total +" + qty*price
                + " WHERE model_ID=" + item.getModel().getId()
                + "  AND cart_ID=" + item.getCart().getId());
        q.executeUpdate();

        tr.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        // handle exception
    } finally {
        // close session
    }
    incrementCartTotal(item.getCart(), NumberUtilities.parseDouble(item.getSubTotal()));
}
```

And use these whereever you want

```
...
if(isItemExists(..)){
  update();
}else{
  save();
}
....
```

Hope that helped !

Answer (score 0):

```
  change your query like this :    


Query q = ses.createQuery("UPDATE "
                    + " CartItems "
                    + " SET qty =  " + qty + " , sub_total = " + qty * unitPrice
                    + " WHERE model_ID=" + c1.getModel().getId()
                    + "  AND cart_ID=" + c1.getCart().getId());
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is not the update statement. Data not inserted. If data already exists, update is working fine.